# match certain string using match and regex failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myString = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MftOONlDQac'
var checkIsYT = myString.match('/youtube/i');
```

I tried above code, but why `checkIsTY` equals to false?

Comment: Why did you expect it to match? There are some differences in the strings ...

Answer (score 3):

Change the second line to:

```
var checkIsYT = myString.match(/youtube/i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing your string to a literal `"/youtube/i"` here. If you want to compare to a regular expression, you don't need the quotes:

```
var checkIsYT = myString.match(/youtube/i);
```